# Laravel dispatching jobs to default Queue even though another queue is explicitly specified

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, queue

I'm scheduling Laravel jobs through kernel.php. I use the following syntax:

```
$schedule->job((new ExampleJob()->onQueue('explicitQueue'))->everyFifteenMinutes();
```

However, a few jobs get dispatched to the default queue instead of the queue that I pass explicitly. Wondering why there is this inconsistency. There is no other place in the code where I dispatch any jobs. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**

I've already tried passing in the queue as a second parameter, and I also tried explicitly setting the `$this->queue` property in my job class however I still got the same *inconsistent* behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the queue name as the second argument to `job` method. So it should be

```php
$schedule->job(new ExampleJob, 'explicitQueue')->everyFifteenMinutes();
```

Relevant documentation page is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs).

Comment: I did try that indeed and still got the same behavior